# Баг в ie6 в списке ul

Tags: internet-explorer, css

Собственно есть меню, следующего вида:

```
<ul id="sidebar">
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#">NUM_1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">NUM_2</a></li>
  </ol>             
  <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">PAGE</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```

и следующий `css`-код:

```
#sidebar {
width: 100%;
display: block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#sidebar li, #sidebar ol li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
}
#sidebar li {
border: 1px solid #bcc6cf;
margin: 10px 0 0;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #40566b;
}
#sidebar ol li {
background-color: #d1caca;
border: 0 none;
}
#sidebar ol {
border: 1px solid #bcc6cf;
margin: 0 10px;
}
#sidebar li a {
width: 100%;
text-decoration:none;
color: #f2f2f2;
font: 18px/24px Stencil, Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

В результате на экране, то как задумывалось (`Chrome, Firefox`) слева и `ie6` справа:

[image: menu]

Видно, что по какой-то причине `ol` (или любой другой тег, или даже просто строка) отображается так как будто он находится внутри тега `li`, хотя тег уже закрыт. Помогите достичь результата в `ie6` как в обычных браузерах.

Comment: Всем спасибо за дельные ответы. переделал меню, теперь везде отображается нормально... что же касается саркастического замечания Dionisа и его подпевал на счет старика осла, то оптимизировать приходится и под него, что мне особого удовольствия не доставляет...Тем не менее на 6-ке сидит еще достаточно народу, чтобы так просто сбрасывать его со счетов

Answer (score 2):

Не дело это ol внутрь ul вставлять. Делаете не по правилами и получаете не верный результат. В чем проблема?

Хром и лиса за ваши ошибки исправили и, наверное, выдали что-то вроде этого:

```
<ul id="sidebar">
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
</ul>
<ol>
  <li><a href="#">NUM_1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">NUM_2</a></li>
</ol>             
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">PAGE</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: да, я уже это пробовал, глюк действительно убирается, но почему нельзя вместить что либо после закрытого li (вот просто текст или тег p, да что угодно))):
    <ul id="sidebar">
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      это текст...это текст...это текст...             
      <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">PAGE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    </ul>
т.к. li всегда шириной 100% то этот текст должен переносится на новую строчку и не запихиваться в этот li

Comment: А почему нельзя поехать по левой стороне дороги? Такие правила.

Comment: Если уж на то пошло, то вложенные списки правильно оформлять так (из основ, 1-ая четверть):

    <ul>
        <li>List 1</li>
        <li>List 2
            <ul>
                <li>Sub List 1</li>
                <li>Sub List 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>List 3</li>
    </ul>

P.S. А вообще, радует сама суть вопроса. @rampage, а в IE5 и IE4 всё нормально? Багов нет? ))

Comment: не забудьте в `netscape` проверить.

Comment: и про Lynx забыли!